# Отображение даты создания записи

Tags: javascript, php

Например создаю блок в котором пишу "машина такая то и такая то" и когда сохраняю в коде, сделать чтобы потом показывалось дата ее создания ! Если сегодня создал то написано "Сегодня", если прошел один день то "вчера", если 2 дня прошло то "2 дня назад" ! то есть как это сделать чтобы они подставлялись в определенное время после создания ? Как в контакте пишется после добавления фильма там так же!  Заранее спасибо если кто подскажет !

Comment: сохраняете дату в базе данных, потом сравниваете с текущей и от этого пляшете, вряд ли кто готовый код даст

Comment: Я так понимаю, вычисление даты происходит с помощью JS, сервер лишь передаёт два timestamp'а. В вопросе стоит уточнить, нужна ли не только дата, но и время, скажем, «2 часа назад».

Comment: Щас не в тему, но за подобные даты ("сегодня", "вчера" etc) готов убивать. Нет, не просто убивать, а убивать с особой жестокостью.

А по теме - ничего не понятно. Кто выводит, что на входе, откуда, в каком формате приходит...

Comment: Сайт без базы данных? Может как-то чтобы я сам вводил точку отсчета, без определния настоящего времени! Главное чтобы не обратный отсчет был, а отсчет "вперед"

Comment: Просто создаю блок сам в коде и хочу чтобы он начал отсчет времени не в обратном направлении до определенной даты (благо на это в интернете хватает готовых решений) а вперед и без определенной даты ) просто чтобы считал часы минуты дни только вперед )

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, вам поможет вот эта библиотека [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

> A javascript date library for parsing, validating, manipulating, and formatting dates.